# Azure Pipeline - Build C# Project with .NET 8 RC2 SDK fails

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

We have an Azure Function app project, which builds fine locally with .NET 8 RC2 SDK. However, when building via the Azure Pipeline, it fails during the restoring of NuGet packages step, and throws the below error :

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(D:\a\1\s\some.API.csproj : error : Could not resolve SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk". 
Exactly one of the probing messages below indicates why we could not resolve the SDK. Investigate and resolve that message to correctly specify the SDK.

D:\a\1\s\SOME.API.csproj : error :   Unable to locate the .NET SDK. Check that it is installed, your PATH is configured for the correct architecture, and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.

D:\a\1\s\SOME.API.csproj : error :   The NuGetSdkResolver did not resolve this SDK because there was no version specified in the project or global.json.

D:\a\1\s\SOME.API.csproj : error :   MSB4276: The default SDK resolver failed to resolve SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk" because directory "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\Sdk" did not exist.

D:\a\1\s\SOME.API.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. No .NET SDKs were found.
```

In the step prior to this, the .NET 8.0.x SDK is downloaded successfully, the pipeline is enabled with "include preview versions" for the "Use .NET Core" task step.

Any ideas what the cause for this error is?

Comment: Make sure that there is no global.json file in your project or if it exists, ensure it is pointing to a valid .NET SDK version. 
The global.json file is used to specify the .NET SDK version for the project.

Comment: Yes, tried both cases - with and without `global.json` file - same result. After installing the latest 8.0 rc2 sdk, the next step in the pipeline is `nuget restore` which is complaining that sdk is not found. Weird. What else should be checked?

Comment: Could be this? "IMPORTANT .NET SDK 8.0.100-rc.2 must be used with Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 3" That's not installed on the hosted runner... Your path to msbuild doesn't include a "Preview" in the folder path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue when I build a .NET 8 project using NuGet restore task.

```
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
 
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```

Then I tried to use DotNet restore task, this time it works.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
```

After checking the detailed logs of the two tasks, I found that in NuGet restore task, "`msBuildVersion`":"`17.7.2.0`". In  DotNet restore task, `MSBuild version` = "`17.8.0+6cdef4241`".

As mentioned by jessehouwing and in this [Announcing .NET 8 Release Candidate 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-8-rc2/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website),

> .NET SDK 8.0.100-rc.2 must be used with Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 3

Based on the above situation, this problem is indeed related to the VS version (msBuildVersion).  DotNet restore task will use the latest .NET 8.0.x SDK in build. So,the workaround is use DotNet restore task instead of NuGet restore task.

Update:

In dotnet build, DotNet restore runs implicitly (See [Implicit restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#implicit-restore)). As the restore step is successful, you can add the argument `'--no-restore'` to disable restore in build step.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore'
  name:   build
```

Comment: Used this, now the dotnet restore step succeeded, but the build task failed, with error as "Response status code does not indicate success: **401 (Unauthorized)**.

C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2\NuGet.targets(156,5): 
error : `Unable to load the service index` for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<companyNAME>/89a0<GUID>9b2/_packaging/<product>/nuget/v3/index.json." - Looks like the build host is not able to authenticate itself to get our company's custom Nuget packages.

Comment: Hi @Anand Sowmithiran, in dotnet build, DotNet restore runs implicitly. As the restore step is successful, please try to add the argument '--no-restore' to disable restore in build step. I added the yaml sample in the answer.

Comment: "@miao-tian-msft" Thanks, the pipeline completed successfully, after I added the --no-restore argument to the build step. Now, I need to deploy to the Az function app.